# Best way to select a city from a list of cities unevenly distributed among countries

Tags: search, lists, select, country

I'm working for a company that owns restaurants in **28 cities distributed in 10 countries**. The restaurants are **distributed unevenly** in the countries: in some countries they are present in many cities but in most countries they have restaurants only one.

For each city, we have a page that lists all the restaurants in that city (ex: Restaurants in Madrid).

**I've been told to design the way the user would get to the city page**. I've considered some options but all of them seem to have problems:

- Search with autosuggest (it works for finding your city but most cities would have no results)
- Tabs by country (but most tabs have only 1 item/city)
- List with all cities (28 cities are a lot for a list)

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Who is the user here? And is there a top level page you're thinking of here? This forum works best when you have some visuals showing the larger context, so the community can help with your specific situation?

Comment: how many countries ?

Comment: Did you consider exploring maps? ex: a map when zoomed out has 10 pins that show the count of cities in each pin (a.k.a country). When clicking on one pin, it will zoom in to one country with the pin distributed to various cities (now each pin will show the number of restaurants in each city).

Comment: Have you considered an accordion list. First it will have 10 closed accordions - with country name on the left, cities count in a badge and chevron to the right. Open the accordion and the same structure repeats, but this time with list of cities on the left, restaurant count in a badge and CTA on the right.

Comment: @Kishan Yes, I have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many other ways to display the information, but without knowing more details it is hard to determine what would be the optimal way to show the details.

But in terms of providing alternatives to what you have listed there, here are some that you can consider:

- Map view with countries highlighted and cities displayed with pins (zoom level for pins need to be considered if there are multiple restaurants in the same city)
- List of countries with cities as sub lists
- Grid layout of countries, which takes you to a subpage of cities or the main page if there is only one restaurant in that country